# How can I prevent pandoc from inserting an <h1> element of my title in the content

Tags: pandoc, epub

I have a book made of several ordered Markdown files. I am using Pandoc to convert those into an epub file, and things are mostly okay. I can embed the font I like and provide my own CSS, etc. The problem is that the output file contains an  element that is not present in the Markdown (as a "#" header element). This element is then being picked up by the ToC function and inserted into the Table of Contents. I didn't ask for the element to be present, and I can't find an option to turn it off.

Here's how to reproduce, with a much simpler case than my actual one, but it's sufficient to demonstrate the problem. I have the following file structure:

```
- pandoctest/
  - src/
    - file1.md
    - file2.md
  - epub.yml
```

The contents are as follows:

**file1.md:**

```
Here is some text.
```

**file2.md:**

```
# Chapter one

The chapter goes here.
```

**epub.yml:**

```
---
title:
  - type: main
    text: A Book
creator:
  - role: author
    text: Some Dude
---
```

And the pandoc command I'm running is:

```
 pandoc -o output.epub epub.yml --toc src/*
```

The end result is something like this:

**Page 1:** An appropriate title page using the title and author elements from `epub.yml`

**Page 2:** The table of contents page. At the top, the title from `epub.yml`. Beneath that are two ToC entries. The first is the title of the book and refers to the element I don't want present on the next page. The second is "Chapter One" which refers to the `# Chapter One` element from my Markdown (this is appropriate).

**Page 3:** First, the undesired element, which, in the raw XML looks like this:

`<h1 class="unnumbered" data-number="">A Book</h1>`

Then, "Here is some text", a paragraph that I did indeed tell it to put there.

**Page 4:** A correctly rendered "Chapter One" page.

The question here is how to get pandoc to not render the "unnumbered" header element that is not present in the Markdown. It screws up the Table of Contents and I never asked for it to be there.

For reference, here is the epub that is rendered from my little test here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dj4jo08g7q4f9i2/output.epub?dl=0

Comment: You're talking about the title page I guess? [Quoting jgm](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6097): "Why do you want to omit the title page: it's a standard part of a book?"

Comment: No, it's not the title page. The title page is what I have listed as "Page 1" in the post. This element comes on Page 3, which is the page made out of the `file1.md` file. That file contains only a paragraph, but winds up looking as though it had `# A Book` at the top that it doesn't actually have. This header then appears in the table of contents.

Comment: But you're talking about the string `A Book`, right? And that only shows up in your input in the `title` field... so pretty sure this is the title page?

Comment: If Page 3 is the title page, then what is Page 1? The information from the yaml file are automatically turned into a title page that reads with the title and author. And why is the title page lumped in with one of the Markdown files. This at least gives me an idea. If I put in an empty header, pandoc should read that as time to create a new page, and at least the page I care most about will look the way I want, even if there's an eroneous additional title on its own. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Did you try the latest pandoc version? Can you upload a zip containing all input files so I can try to reproduce?

Comment: Here's a simple zip file that reproduces the problem using the steps and files I listed in my original post: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oy3yzcbf0svnqef/epub-test.zip?dl=0 I checked and I am running pandoc 2.9.2.1 on Fedora 34. This is the latest version of pandoc available in the package repositories.

Comment: I just downloaded the latest pandoc release from Github. It's 2.13. The behavior is identical and reproducible in that version as well.

Comment: The `src` folder is unfortunately empty in the dropbox zip. To debug the  `output.epub`, you can rename it to `output.zip` and unzip to see what's going on inside..